# What Pidgin protocol should I choose for gmail?

Tags: pidgin

I want to open a Pidgin account.

My OS is Scientific Linux 6 just in case that's an issue.

I clicked on 'Add' and the first thing to select is Protocol.

The contents of the list are:

```
AIM,Bonjour,Facebook,Gadu-Gadu,GoogleTalk,GroupWise,ICQ,IRC,MSN,MXit,
MySpaceIM,QQ,SIMPLE,Sametime,XMPP,Yahoo,Yahoo Japan,Zephyr.
```

I use gmail but it is not on the dropdown list.

I don't use anything else on that list.

Which Protocol should I choose?

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/324863/332092

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application Gmail uses for chat is actually GoogleTalk (or Hangouts, or whatever they've rebranded it to this week); from there, it's quite simple to deduce that the protocol you want is, in fact, GoogleTalk. (And no, I'm not just deducing the answer; I use Pidgin for Google chat almost exclusively, and this is how I always set it up.)

Worth noting that under the hood it's just XMPP, and before Pidgin added GoogleTalk as a "protocol" you would actually use that one; rumor has it you still can, but I've never had any luck, and just using GoogleTalk is simpler. (As an aside, Facebook's the same in this respect.)

Answer (score 1):

Google has announced that XMPP access will cease in June 2022. (I can not find the announcement now)
(Facebook stopped using XMPP a bunch of years ago)